# How do I set up firebase in a react project to connect to the right firebase console account?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, visual-studio-code, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on a react project in VS Code but whenever I try to connect to firebase functions using the 'firebase init' command, it does not show the right project in my email. It's showing a project in another email of mine.

I cannot remember how or when I linked the project to connect to the email from where it is currently showing projects.

How do I correct my project configuration to connect to the right firebase account so that it can pick the right project?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#admin-commands, Firebase logout then firebase login

Comment: Hi @InnocentOyebode. I will post my comment as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply run:

```
 firebase logout
```

Then:

```
firebase login
```

It will ask for your project.

For reference: [CLI administrative commands](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#admin-commands)

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
firebase logout
```

And then

```
firebase login
```